# Optimal regex to extract a single decimal number in an arbitrary string

Tags: java, regex, optimization

Assuming a target string that's on one hand arbitrary but, on the other hand, guaranteed to contain a single decimal number (1 or more digits), I came up with the following regular regex pattern:

```
.*?(\d+).*?
```

So, if the target string is "(this is number 200)", for example, `Matcher.group(1)` will contain the number.

Is there a more optimal regex pattern (or non-regex method) to extract this number?

By "optimal" I mean *fastest* (possibly with the least amount of CPU cycles). Java only.

Comment: If you really want to nitpick, the optimal solution (assuming you really do have arbitrary strings as input of course) would be to just loop over the String's characters directly.  it would save you a whole couple of CPU cycles. ;)

Comment: Why does it need to be "optimal"? Are you doing it a billion times a second? Or are you programming a watch from the seventies on which you ported a JVM? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure regex and parseInt will perform well enough for you.  However for your interest, I have compared it with a simple loop.

```
public static final Pattern DIGITS = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String text = "Some text before a number 123456 and some after";
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    timeRegex(text);
    timeLooping(text);
  }
}

private static int timeLooping(String text) {
  int ret = 0;
  final int runs = 1000;
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  for (int r = 0; r < runs; r++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
      char ch = text.charAt(i);
      if (ch <= '9' && ch >= '0')
        ret = ret * 10 + ch - '0';
      else if (ret > 0)
        break;
    }
  }
  long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
  System.out.printf("Took %,d ns to use a loop on average%n", time / runs);
  return ret;
}

private static int timeRegex(String text) {
  int ret = 0;
  final int runs = 1000;
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  for (int r = 0; r < runs; r++) {
    Matcher m = DIGITS.matcher(text);
    if (m.find())
      ret = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
  }
  long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
  System.out.printf("Took %,d ns to use a matcher on average%n", time / runs);
  return ret;
}
```

prints

```
Took 19,803 ns to use a matcher on average
Took 85 ns to use a loop on average
Took 12,411 ns to use a matcher on average
Took 83 ns to use a loop on average
Took 8,199 ns to use a matcher on average
Took 79 ns to use a loop on average
Took 11,156 ns to use a matcher on average
Took 104 ns to use a loop on average
Took 4,527 ns to use a matcher on average
Took 94 ns to use a loop on average
```

Comment: WOW! I guess that answers @Bart Kiers's question which sadly reflects the mindset of "mainstream programming" nowadays.

Comment: Never thought of myself as mainstream more special ... needs. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just (\d+) is more than enough.

Comment: You are correct, but since this produces *false* for `matches()` I was wondering whether this is actually less optimal. Is that so? +1.

Comment: @Regex Rookie: `matches` is just stoopid, because Java in its infinite stupidity decided to redefine what matches has always meant in programming. Never use it. Since you can implement `matches` using `find`, but cannot implement `find` using `matches`, that means that `matches` is unnecessary cruft that just confuses people. As many have found.

Comment: @tchrist I knew that my question will lead to new insights for me. :) Thanks +1 for the explanation.

Comment: @tchrist Huh? Sure you can replace matches with find - but then the same is true for almost any construct in programming languages (church has proven that after all). The definition is trivial and considering that regex are used often enough as validity checks that's a nice simplification.